# Why does escript outputs different result?

Tags: erlang, escript

It's a simple and well-known test script:

```erlang
-module(processes).
-compile(export_all).

max(N)->
    Max=erlang:system_info(process_limit),
    io:format("the max processes is ~p ~n",[Max]),
    statistics(runtime),
    statistics(wall_clock),
    L=for(1,N,fun()->spawn(fun()->wait() end) end),
    {_,Time1}=statistics(runtime),
    {_,Time2}=statistics(wall_clock),
    lists:foreach(fun(Pid)->Pid!die end,L),
    U1=Time1*1000/N,
    U2=Time2*1000/N,
    io:format("the proecess time is ~p:~p ~n",[U1,U2]).

wait()->
    receive
        die->void
    end.

for(N,N,F)->[F()];
for(I,N,F)->[F()|for(I+1,N,F)].

main([])->
    max(100000).
```

Here is the output of erl:

```
$ erl 
Erlang/OTP 17 [erts-6.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V6.2  (abort with ^G)
1> c(processes)
1> processes:max(100000).
* 2: syntax error before: processes
1> c(processes).         
{ok,processes}
2> processes:max(100000).
the max processes is 262144 
the proecess time is 1.1:4.35 
ok
```

Here is the output of escript:

```
$ escript processes.erl
the max processes is 262144 
the proecess time is 47.8:83.4
```

What's the exact difference between escript and erl?
I'm a newbie of erlang, please help!

**Edit:**

When escript runs beam file, it output same result as erl:

```
$ escript processes.beam
the max processes is 262144 
the proecess time is 1.8:3.33
```

What happens? I know *.beam is compiled codes, but escript does not compile the script before running it? I'm still confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that your second run is being interpreted, while your first run was compiled. Run

```
escript -c processes.erl
```

and you'll get a time that is basically the same. You can also get this behavior by putting the directive `-mode(compile).` in your script.

From [the documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html):

> Execution of interpreted code is slower than compiled code. If much of
>   the execution takes place in interpreted code it may be worthwhile to
>   compile it, even though the compilation itself will take a little
>   while. It is also possible to supply native instead of compile, this
>   will compile the script using the native flag, again depending on the
>   characteristics of the escript this could or could not be worth while.
>
> As mentioned earlier, it is possible to have a script which contains
>   precompiled beam code. In a precompiled script, the interpretation of
>   the script header is exactly the same as in a script containing source
>   code. That means that you can make a beam file executable by
>   prepending the file with the lines starting with #! and %%! mentioned
>   above. In a precompiled script, the function main/1 must be exported.

If you're interested in the precompiled option, you may want to check out the build tool [rebar](http://www.rebar3.org), which has an `escriptize` command for turning all your code into a pre-compiled archive with the appropriate escript header.

For the mechanism of interpreting/compiling used, you can check out [the source code to escript](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/stdlib/src/escript.erl). What you'll see is that escript in `interpret` mode is equivalent (modulo some syntax) to pasting your code into the `erl` interactive interpreter line by line.

Comment: Thanks for your detail answer! What's the exact representation of codes within the erlang vm? I thought anyway the source files would be converted into bytecodes just like other languages, e.g. python. The compile means bytecode conversion? Then I thought escript must do it before running anyway.

Comment: I added a little more detail. I believe Python compiles before running (defaulting to something like escript's `-c` mode). I suspect that on a modern PC or faster, the compilation cost is so small that you'd always want to compile your escripts before running (because most of the time it will cost a few ms and occasionally it will save seconds).